# Is there a way to pull all select menu’s selected index in my html to add values to different arrays of my choice. A lot of code for 1 select menu

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-operator

The function finds which tv character the user compares to based on their    answers to my questions. My code now is very inefficient for multiple select menus!!!  Maybe an object that takes all selectmenus in html and allows me to assign array values based on the selected index of a selectmenu.

```
function onSelectMenuBlur() {

    "use strict";
    /*list of arrays that will be  added to when the user selects an option in a selectmenu.*/
    var rickArray = [];
    var shaneArray = [];
    var bobArray = [];
    var carolArray = [];
    var lArray = [];
    var sm = document.getElementById("selectmenu");
```

.onchange function that determines what array will be added to depending   on the option selected in the select menu.  This function will add an array value of 1 once to an array. Seems like an inefficient way, especially with multiple selectmenus!

```
     sm.onchange = function() {

        if(sm.selectedIndex + 1 === 1) {
            rickArray.push(1);
            shaneArray.pop();
            bobArray.pop();
            carolArray.pop();
            lArray.pop();
            alert(rickArray.length);            
            }
        else if(sm.selectedIndex + 1 === 2) {
            shaneArray.push(1);
            rickArray.pop();
            bobArray.pop();
            carolArray.pop();
            lArray.pop();
            alert(shaneArray.length);           
            }
        else if(sm.selectedIndex + 1 === 3) {
            bobArray.push(1);
            rickArray.pop();
            shaneArray.pop();
            carolArray.pop();
            lArray.pop();
            alert(bobArray.length);         
            }
        else if(sm.selectedIndex + 1 === 4) {
            carolArray.push(1);
            rickArray.pop();
            shaneArray.pop();
            bobArray.pop();
            lArray.pop();
            alert(carolArray.length);           
            }
        else if(sm.selectedIndex + 1 === 5) {
            lArray.push(1);
            rickArray.pop();
            shaneArray.pop();
            bobArray.pop();
            carolArray.pop();
            alert(lArray.length);           
            }
            else{}

    };
```

.onblur purpose to find array with biggest length or value out of all    selectmenus to determine which person associated with the array the user is  like. Again seems like an inefficient way to handle!

```
    sm.onblur = function() {

        var rickL = rickArray.length;

        var shaneL = shaneArray.length;

        var bobL = bobArray.length;

        var carolL = carolArray.length;

        var lL = lArray.length;

          // unfinished if else statement !!
 if(rickL > shaneL && rickL > bobL && rickL > carolL && rickL > lL) {
        alert("you are Rick Grimes");
    }
    else{
        alert("you are someone else");
        }
    };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a 2-dimensional array instead of separate arrays for each character, and then use the selected index as an index into the array.

```
var characters = [[], [], [], [], []];

sm.onchange = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        if (i == this.selectedIndex) {
            characters[i].push(1);
            alert(characters[i].length);
        } else {
            characters[i].pop();
        }
    }
};
```

To get the character names in there, make it an array of objects.

```
characters = [
    { name: "Rick",
      array: []
    },
    { name: "Carol",
      array: []
    },
    ...
}
```

Then you would use `characters[i].array.push(1)`. And then when you want to say which character they are, find the object with the longest array and then print its `.name`.

Comment: Hi Barmar Thanks for the help! Using an object of arrays for the characters is great, but shouldn't the for loop use characters[i].array.push(1) instead of character[i].push(1) or does it have a different purpose? @Barmar

Comment: That's what I said in the sentence beginning with "Then you would use".

Comment: The loop at the top of the answer is using a 2-dimensional array. The array of objects is a change to that.

Comment: so the first for loop is used to make an array of the select menu and the select menu's selected index. For example,     [0, 5]  0 = selectmenu  5 = selected option ? @Barmar

Comment: It's a 2-dimensional array. If the selected index is 3, the array will contain `[[], [], [], [1], []]` because you push `1` onto the array in index 3 of the array.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure why you're using arrays in the first place. Why not just counters that you add and subtract from?

Comment: Basically, `characters[0]` replaces `rickArray`, `characters[1]` is `shaneArray`, and so on.

Comment: Thank You!! Now I Understand a 2-D array.  Thanks for being patient, I'm restarting to learn javascript after a year or so of not doing any.  I've made changes to my code, but I'm still having errors @Barmar